RNEncryptedStorage is undefined after updating to the newest react native version
I recently updated my React Native project to the newest version, and now I'm experiencing a problem. The error message isn't clear, and I've been unable to pinpoint the root cause. Here's some context and the code for my test case.
My App.test.js
/**
 * @format
 */

import "react-native";
import React from "react";
import App from "../App";

// Note: import explicitly to use the types shipped with jest.
import { it } from "@jest/globals";

// Note: test renderer must be required after react-native.
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";

it("renders correctly", () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});


Although the test doesn't fail, I still encounter issues when running the app. I've double-checked the Jest setup, and it appears to be correct. I've also looked through related questions and documentation, but couldn't find a suitable solution.
I tried adding some mock tests I found in the web but non of them worked.
